# Do I always need to unsubscribe events of nested class instances in Blazor WASM razor page?

Tags: c#, events, garbage-collection, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a `ClosestEvents.razor` page with this code behind:

```
public partial class ClosestEvents: IDisposable
{
    private MyEventSource Source;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Source = new MyEventSource();
        Source.OnDataUpdated += StateHasChanged;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if(Source != null)
            Source.OnDataUpdated -= StateHasChanged;
    }
}
```

Do I always have to manually unsubscribe and as a consequence implement a `Dispose` method?
As I know not unsubscribing can cause memory will not collected by GC but I guess in this case subscriber and source both will be available for GC. Can I not usbubscribe in this case? Will GC handle this well?
Something like this:

```
public partial class ClosestEvents
{
    private MyEventSource Source;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Source = new MyEventSource();
        Source.OnDataUpdated += StateHasChanged;
    }
}
```

Comment: Putting code in a Using Block will automatically mark an object to get disposed.  GC is run in background in windows,  Object are marked for disposing in code and then windows will dispose either in background and/or when needed (low on memory).  Class object in c# are ByRef and can have multiple links to each object.  There is an external link count to each class object.  The managed c# will only dispose an object when the external link count is zero to prevent Blue Screen Exception so object that are still referenced do not get disposed.

Comment: Mistyped, it Source everywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will GC handle this well?

Yes.

`Source.OnDataUpdated += StateHasChanged;` creates a reference from the Source element to the Component this is in.

But because it is declared as `private MyEventSource Source;` the Source has the same lifetime (GC reachability) as the owner.

You do not have to unsubscribe events like this. And I wouldn't, it's clutter.

Answer (score 1):

When you register a handler for an event, the object that owns that event [the source] has a reference to the handler instance [the consumer].

That reference is only released when either:

1. You unregister the handler.
2. The source goes out of scope and is destroyed by the GC.  At which point the reference to the consumer is released.

So the answer depends on the scope of `MyEventSource`.  If it's component/page scoped, technically you don't need to un-register.  Everything will go out of scope at the same time.

If it has a wider scope, such as a service, then you need to.

My basic rule:  Unregister everything.

Note: `Dispose` is called by the Renderer when it "detaches" a component from the render tree before it releases it's references to it.